# Update to mapred-default.xml not visible in web UI configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, hadoop-yarn, kylin

I have an Apache Kylin container running in docker. I was getting a Java heap space error in map reduce phase so I tried updating some parameters in Hadoop mapred-default.xml file. After making the changes, I restarted the container but, when I go to Yarn ResourceManager Web UI and then to Configuration:

[image: Yarn ResourceManager Web UI screenshot]

An xml file is opened, looking like this:

[image]

However my new values for the properties that I set inside the mapred-default.xml are not here, it is showing the old values for those properties... Does anyone have any idea why that is happening and what I should do to make it register the new values? I tried restarting the container, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a default value for a property, specify the new value within the  tags, inside `mapred-site.xml` not `mapred-default.xml`, using the following format:

```
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
 <value>1024</value>
</property>
```

Be sure restart yarn after reconfigure by `stop-yarn.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`.